# Javascript scroll event problem on Android Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, scroll

I made a website that loads a certain amount of DOM elements whenever the user approaches near the bottom of the page as long as there are things to load from my database. I made it to reduce page loading time and put it at the bottom of the body.
It works perfectly on all pc browsers and it works fine on mobile devices in chrome/firefox developer phone simulation. (*side note: I have tested it on a lot of the phones there).
However,when I test in on real phone,window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){...}); works **only if i start scrolling in 1.5 seconds aprox. after page loading**,in any other case,if I wait it doesnt work,function isnt invoked.
I wont go into uneccesery details and code,I would just write my event listener,if statment which cheks whather user has approached bottom and where have I located script in index file:

```
<html> 
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

mySript.js

```
var productlinks=new Array(18);
/*LOADING PRODUCTS FROM DATABASE IN ARRAYS*/
.....
var counter=0;
var size=productlinks.length-9;
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
if((document.documentElement.scrollTop+document.documentElement.clientHeight>=document.documentElement.scrollHeight-1 ) && ((counter+8)<=size)){
load...
});
```

Comment: I know that function isnt invoked because when I put alert inside if statment it only invokes in above describaded scenario on android Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried to measure the time of executing all the things before that `addEventListener`?

Comment: Well the whole myScript is a big file it has 1000 lines of code,just checked the execution time is 280ms,the index file is 28ms measured on pc.